# I want to retrieve the ElementID that contains a known string

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

C# Selenium Webdriver
So i need to ensure that none of my pages (around 200 pages) contain a particular known string. Is there any way that i can scan a page for the existence of this string and if it does then return both the ElementID of that element and the entire string?
For example my source is like:

```
<a id="cancel_order_lnkCancel">Cancel Order</a>
```

I want to search for the word 'Cancel' on the whole page (`<div id="sitewrapper">`) and return both
cancel_order_lnkCancel;Cancel Order

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath to find by text. e.g.:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(string.Format("//*[contains(text(), '{0}')]", value)));
```

`value` being the string you are searching for.

Then to get the element's markup and content:

```
var html = element.GetAttribute("outerHTML");
var text = element.Text;
```

or

```
var text = element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Comment: Won't it throw exception of element not found?

Comment: Thanks folks, but i want to return the actual Element ID that contains that string as well? I can retrieve a value from my IWelement that looks like 0.45616444828920066-1 but the actual id i want is cancel_order_lnkCancel. hmmmm

Comment: This looks like it will work: myWebElement.GetAttribute("outerHTML");

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked in C# binding but you can use `FindElements` to get a list of all elements containing the text. You can by no doubt use @Jarga's xpath. The good thing with `FIndElements` will be that it won't throw you an exception (atleast this is what happens in java) though you have to use try catch to handle getAttribute if you get null for `value` of `id`. And if you iterate over the list you can fetch all texts using `getText` method.